# MS VC++ Compiler equivocation

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, runtime

In my project, I trying reload global operator new and delete ([] too). And when I try to compile in first time, I get link error:

> Main.obj : error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)"
>   (??2@YAPAXI@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(new.obj)

When I try to compile in second time, errors magically disappear! **But sometimes return.**
How to resolve this problem?

Run-time Library: MTd.

Code:

```
void  operator delete(void * pointer){LALALA}
```

Or

```
void  __cdecl operator delete(void * pointer){LALALA}
```

This error returns when I do follow steps:

1. Remove reloaded new (and other)
2. Compile
3. Again reload
4. Try to compile and get this error

In other case error disappear. What reason for this?

Comment: The file compiles first and gives this error. The second time, the error is not shown because the file is not recompiled if it isn't modified. Please post the line that gives you the error.

Answer (score -1):

you have to implicitly declare 'new' and 'delete' as a static member function

void* operator new (size_t size);

void operator delete (void *p);

Comment: No, statics opeators new and delete no call =(